# Facial Recognition using Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, facial-identification

So I am working on a project and one of the many parts of it includes identifying faces within an image. I have done bunch of research based on what I nee, and the default frontal face haarcascade doesn't work for my needs. I however, have found another haarcascade that was trained on a more suitable database(UMIST). I want use the new cascade instead, but there is this error I received.

`error: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set`

I am assuming it is the custom haarcascade just not working.

I am probably just missing something that is very obvious, or my custom haarcascde just won't work. If it is just the haarcascde that doesn't work, then is there another way I can use another haarcascade?

Note: [Here](https://github.com/sonots/tutorial-haartraining/blob/master/result/haarcascade_profileface_umist1.xml) is the link to the GitHub with the UMIST haarcascade
also I did move the UMIST cascade into the cv2 cascade data folder so that is not the issue.

It did just occur to me that the UMIST data could be outdated and Opencv2 just can't use it? I am not sure, any help would be awesome!

Here is the projects source code:

```
import cv2
import sys

targetImage = 1
ImagePath = 'image-9.jpg'


image = cv2.imread(ImagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



faceCascade2 = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_profileface_umist_1.xml")
faces = faceCascade2.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.3,
    minNeighbors=3,
    minSize=(15, 15)
    )


print("Found {0} Faces".format(len(faces)))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

status = cv2.imwrite("Data/image-9-data.jpg", image)
print("saved",status)
```

Comment: you are sure there is no spelling mistakes in the cascade classfiier file you included? and you are sure there is no need for mentioning the file extension ?

Comment: @venkata krishnan yes I am sure about the spelling, and I believe, to the best of my knowledge, that there is no need for the file extension

Comment: i tried your code, and the problem you are facing is, it wasnt able to locate the file, the xml file. You must specify the extension ".xml" and the corresponding path. If you have root access permission issue, for the cv2 data folder, you can always place the xml file in a relative path(project folder) and refer it directly.

Comment: @venkata krishnan Okay thank you btw, however when I fixed it and it gave me this error: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set

Comment: can you update your new code as edit ? in the question, so that i can check..

Comment: @venkata krishnan it is updated